# How can I use the reduce/reject/map function for Laravel collections?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I'm currently using the `show` function in my `UserController.php` to show all the users belonging to a particular company.

```
/**
   * Show the list of all users.
   *
   * @return Response
   */
  public function show() {
    $users = User::where('status',1)->with(['phones', 'companies'])->get(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']);
    $filteredUsers = [];
    foreach($users as $user){
      foreach($user->companies as $company){
        if($company->id == session('selected_company')){
          $filteredUsers[] = $user;
        }
      }
    }
    return view('users', ['team_members' => $filteredUsers]);
  }
```

This works perfectly fine, but I want to make the code more elegant with Laravel collections, hopefully with a `map()`, `reject()` or `reduce()` function

How can I do so?

I tried the `reject()` function but it keeps showing me all the users in the database. Here's what I tried:

```
/**
   * Show the list of all users.
   *
   * @return Response
   */
  public function show() {
    $users = User::where('status',1)->with(['phones','companies'])->get(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']);

    $userCollection = collect($users);
    $filteredUsers = $userCollection->reject(function ($value) {
      $userCompanies = collect($value->companies);
      // if user companies contain the id, return that user
      if($userCompanies->contains('id', session('selected_company'))){
         return $value;
      }

    });

    return view('users', ['team_members' => $filteredUsers->all()]);
  }
```

Comment: You can make your code more elegant if you filter users by company in eloquent / sql, rather than fetching all users from database and rejecting/reducing it in php.

Comment: @AlexBlex I figured that, but the companies data is in a separate table. How can I filter that using eloquent?

Comment: Yes, of course it is.There are several ways to achieve that: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations,  https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#joins, or even raw sql. Please try and ask another question if you have any problems with fetching such data.

Comment: @AlexBlex Ah I see. Thanks for that. Unfortunately Laravel 5.2 documentation doesn't say anything about `has` or `whereHas`.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to make collect again $users,try like this

```
$names = $users->reject(function ($user) {
                    return $user->active === false;
                 })->map(function ($user) {
                    return $user->name;
                 });
```

Comment: This would certainly get rid of the `('status',1)` portion, but I was kinda hoping to do the same thing instead of the 2 `foreach` loops there. :) Any clue?